# Python : how to add column above excel xlsx file when crawling data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, web-crawler

Hi I am a code newbie an I am trying to get news titles from cnn.com just like the image of an excel file attached below.

However the problem is, that I don't know how to add each columns, such as World/Politics/Health and my code get data only from LAST element of the tuple list (in this code, 'politics').

So here is my code. Thank you in advance!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from bs4 import NavigableString
import re
import xlsxwriter
from openpyxl import Workbook


path = "C:/Users/Desktop/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

# per section

a =['world','health','politics']
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for i in a:
    nl = []
    driver.get("https://edition.cnn.com/"+str(i))
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    find_ingre = soup.select("span.cd__headline-text")

    for i in find_ingre:
        nl.append(i.get_text())

# make dataframe --> save xlsx

import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

df = pd.DataFrame(nl)
df.to_excel("cnn_recent_topics.xlsx",index=False)
```

result now --->
[image: result now]

result that I want to get --->
[image: result that I want to get]

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this, comment if you need explaination:

```
def custom_scrape(topic):
    nl = []
    driver.get("https://edition.cnn.com/"+str(topic))
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    find_ingre = soup.select("span.cd__headline-text")

    for i in find_ingre:
        nl.append(i.get_text())


    return nl

topics =['world','health','politics']
result = pd.DataFrame()
for topic in topics:
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame(nl)
    temp_df.columns = [topic]
    result = pd.concat([result, temp_df], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi, actually the code gives me several 'NameError', don't know exactly why. Can you add some explanation?